# Wait for message from server using socket and thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, wait

please excuse my spelling, im french, i'll try to do my best.

Im creating an app that comunicate with a server using socket. It's a chat app with my school chatting protocol. The server can send me message anytime. I insist on the "anytime". I though about making a while(true) loop in a thread but it seems not to work.

To sum up :  i want to wait for messages from the server.

Any help apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess ur talking abt java.
If you just need to read from server , one one thread is needed. The InputStreamReader will wait till it gets some message. But if you are using some gui for showing the result and have only one thread, the program will looks like dead, As no execution will happen during the waiting time. 
hence u need to put the reading part in seperate thread.

for example:

```
class Reader implements Runnable{
    Scanner scan=null;
    public Reader(Scanner scan){
    this.scan=scan;
    new Thread(this).start();
}
public void run(){
    while(true){
        putToGui(scan.next());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah actually the while(true) worked. Server was just doing craps. Thanks for your answer ;)